# Mega SDK: dependency errors

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, github

I am trying to build the mega SDK from github inside visual studio 2013, but I cannot get the dependencies right!

What did I do:

1. I Downloaded the project from: [Github MEGA SDK](https://github.com/meganz/sdk)
2. I Opened the visual studio project located in: `examples\win32`
3. I read the readme found: [Mega Visual Studio Readme](https://github.com/meganz/sdk/blob/master/examples/win32/README.md) and downloaded all the third part dependencies
4. I Added Includes to these folders:

[image: Inlcude directories]

I am still getting a **lot of errors** and I cannot **get the dependencies right** (Right now on sodium/version.h).

Does anybody have an idea **how to fix it or how to get the library to build?**

[**My git repository**](https://github.com/Ghosttje/VSMegaSDK), the startup solution is located:

> C:\Git\VSMegaSDK\examples\win32\MEGAdokan\MEGA.sln

```
Error   99  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   198 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   297 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   396 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   495 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   594 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   693 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   792 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   891 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   990 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1089    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1188    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1287    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1386    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1485    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1584    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1683    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1782    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1881    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   1980    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2083    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2182    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2281    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2380    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2479    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2578    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2677    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2776    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2875    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   2974    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3073    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3172    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3271    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3370    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3469    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3568    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3667    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3766    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3865    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3964    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sodium/version.h': No such file or directory    C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include\sodium.h  48  1   mega
Error   3965    error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory   c:\git\vsmegasdk\examples\win32\megadokan\megadokan.cpp 27  1   MEGAdokan
```

Comment: Please show the contents of directory `C:\Git\TestProjects\C++\Mega\sdk-master\third_party\libsodium\include` and its subdirectory `sodium`. That is where I would expect the header file `sodium/version.h` to reside. This is to check you have actually installed the Sodium dependency (which the docs marked as *optional*, requiring the `--with-sodium` configuration option). I.e., have you double-checked your installation to be correct?

Comment: In the folder that you named there is a file called `version.h.in` but no file called `version.h`. I just extracted the zip from the following website: `libsodium.org`, named in a textfile on the following location: `examples\win32\README.md`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of a `version.h.in` indicates that you have unpacked the software, **but not yet built it**.

(`<file>.in` is traditionally the **in**put file for some processing step that will then yield `<file>`.)

You're looking at the **source** for libsodium. You probably should have picked one of the available **binary** Windows distributions.